# Dialog Material-UI Scroll start from bottom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to put the div scroll with ref tag inside Dialog Material-UI Design I'm getting an error says `Cannot read property 'scrollHeight' of undefined`

If I use my code out of Dialog it works fine here's the example

[Working Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/9r3x0nq0o)

All what I'm trying to do is to make the scroll div to start from the end

I did an example on [Not working with Dialog](https://codesandbox.io/s/k5rr64pvlv)

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider'
import Dialog from 'material-ui/Dialog';
import FlatButton from 'material-ui/FlatButton';
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';

class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      open: false,
    }
  }

  handleOpen = () => {
    this.setState({ open: true });
  };
  handleClose = () => {
    this.setState({ open: false });
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    this.shoppingListContainer.scrollTop = this.shoppingListContainer.scrollHeight;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider>
      <div id="scrolldiv">
          <RaisedButton label="Alert" onClick={this.handleOpen} />
        <Dialog
          title="Dialog With Actions"
          modal={false}
          open={this.state.open}
          onRequestClose={this.handleClose}
        >
        <div>
        <ul style={{
          width: 115,
          height: 100,
          overflow: 'auto',
          border: '2px black solid'
        }}
          ref={(shoppingListContainer) => { this.shoppingListContainer = shoppingListContainer; }}
        >
          <li>Instagram</li>
          <li>WhatsApp</li>
          <li>Oculus</li>
          <li>Instagram</li>
          <li>WhatsApp</li>
          <li>Oculus</li>
          <li>Instagram</li>
          <li>WhatsApp</li>
          <li>Oculus</li>
          <li>Instagram</li>
          <li>WhatsApp</li>
          <li>Oculus</li>

        </ul>
        </div>
          </Dialog>
      </div>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: You can find the answer below, with the running code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a possible solution.

The refs actually work in a pattern, when you define a ref it is
assigned to the Global Execution Context `this`. So that, you can use
them as `this.YourRefName`. But these refs a re not assigned to
`this`, until your component is rendered/mounted completely.

> In your case, you are using a ref of the `<ul>` component as named
>   `shoppingListContainer`. in the method `componentDidMount()` method of
>   the root component of your project, After rendeing the intial view of
>   your project, you can see the `<ul>` component is not rendered yet,
>   That's why the ref you provided is showing undefined.

In such cases you do apply module approach to your component hierarchy. Following is the running code as per your implementation:

```
import React from 'react';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider'
import Dialog from 'material-ui/Dialog';
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';

class ListContainer extends React.Component {
  scrollToBottom = () => {
    this.listContainer.scrollTop = this.listContainer.scrollHeight;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.scrollToBottom();
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.scrollToBottom();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ul style={{
        width: 115,
        height: 100,
        overflow: 'auto',
        border: '2px black solid'
      }}
        ref={(element) => { this.listContainer = element; }}
      >
        <li>Instagram</li>
        <li>WhatsApp</li>
        <li>Oculus</li>
        <li>Instagram</li>
        <li>WhatsApp</li>
        <li>Oculus</li>
        <li>Instagram</li>
        <li>WhatsApp</li>
        <li>Oculus</li>
        <li>Instagram</li>
        <li>WhatsApp</li>
        <li>Oculus</li>

      </ul>
    )
  }

}

class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      open: false,
    }
  }

  handleOpen = () => {
    this.setState({ open: true });
  };
  handleClose = () => {
    this.setState({ open: false });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider>
        <div id="scrolldiv" ref='listC' >
          <RaisedButton label="Alert" onClick={this.handleOpen} />
          <Dialog
            title="Dialog With Actions"
            modal={false}
            open={this.state.open}
            onRequestClose={this.handleClose}
          >
            <div>
              <ListContainer />
            </div>
          </Dialog>
        </div>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

In the code above, I broke the component structure, to make sure reactjs will access the ref, exactly when the component with ref definition is rendered.

It will actually make your approach easy to understand and maintain.

Comment: Wow that's awesome explanation! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because react is not able to find **shoppingListContainer**
You can try this code, it worked for me.

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider'
import Dialog from 'material-ui/Dialog';
import FlatButton from 'material-ui/FlatButton';
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';

class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      open: false,
    }
  }

  handleOpen = () => {
    this.setState({ open: true });
  };
  handleClose = () => {
    this.setState({ open: false });
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    let shoppingListContainer = this.refs.scrolldiv;
    if (shoppingListContainer) {
      shoppingListContainer.style.scrollWidth =
        shoppingListContainer.style.scrollHeight;
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider>
      <div>
          <RaisedButton label="Alert" onClick={this.handleOpen} />
        <Dialog
          title="Dialog With Actions"
          modal={false}
          open={this.state.open}
          onRequestClose={this.handleClose}
        >

            <div className="shopping-list" refs="scrolldiv" 
            style={{
              width: 125,
              height: 100,
              overflow: 'auto',
              border: '2px black solid'
            }}>
              <ul>
                <li>Instagram</li>
                <li>WhatsApp</li>
                <li>Oculus</li>
                <li>Instagram</li>
                <li>WhatsApp</li>
                <li>Oculus</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </Dialog>

      </div>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: the greatest benefit of reactJS is virtualDOM, which actually allows the browser to find/change/update the specific part of the dom which is to be updated via code. This save s cost is time and processing.

Comment: doing a getElementById() again made it go through all the DOM to search fora node. It is a bad approach, even if it solves the problem.

Comment: You corrected the approach but nor solving the problem now. :(